# When to use the tag "meme"?

Tags: support

[Some questions contain the meme tag](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meme). What does this tag mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It should be removed.**

[Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-meme-2483702) describes a meme as:

> A 'meme' is a virally-transmitted cultural symbol or social idea.

They're typically encountered in the form of captioned viral images, [as you can see here](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/memes).

I don't think it's really a great fit to any of the questions it's used for here. I honestly feel that it would be more accurate to say "concept" rather than "meme" here, because there are a lot of connotations of memes being jocular rather than useful, so it seems out of place on a professional DevOps site. Even so, the [culture](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) tag would seem to be sufficient, so I feel [meme](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meme) provides little value and should just be removed from the questions it applies to.

Comment: meme tag has been removed from three questions