# Could someone remove the meme tag?

Tags: support

[When to use the tag "meme"?](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216/when-to-use-the-tag-meme)

The meme tage has been removed from the questions. Could someone remove this tag?

Comment: Tag are removed after one week without question IIRC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags without any questions are [automatically deleted at 3:00 GMT every night](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/336144) by automated scripts, with no human action required, so there's nothing more you need to do once the tag is not used by any questions.

---

The tag has now been deleted.